# Empty rubbish bin on mounted volume on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

When I go to Rubbish Bin on Ubuntu, try to empty, it took a long time. 
Tried command:
    rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*

Still there, BTW my deleted files are on a mounted volume.

Answer (score 0):

Mounted volume is at /media/user/xxdrive, send ll, should display .Trash-1000

cd .Trash-1000

rm -rf * will remove all the trash files.